# Select distinct records and at the same time first occurance of the record from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, innodb

I am not familiar enough with MySQL execution plan so I need help to understand and find out how to operate on a subsets of data in MySQL if it is possible. I have two tables:

Table users:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| msisdn          | bigint(20)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| activation_date | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msisdn_type     | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table log_archive:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msisdn      | bigint(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| msisdn_type | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date        | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| action      | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In table users msisdn is unique but in log_archive it is not.

Here you can find PHP script that will generate you test data for these two tables:

[Test data generation script helper](http://pastebin.com/5vy47jX4)

I need to select:

```
1) All distinct records by msisdn from table log_archive;
2) By earliest date per msisdn for one specific action only;
3) For a specific date range from table log_archive;
4) And to join activation_date from users table with msisdn from both tables.
```

Let me give you example. Let's say that this is sample data from log_archive table:

```
+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
|    msisdn    |    date    |   activation_date   |     action     |
|--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 977129764170 | 2016-02-11 | 2014-10-07 00:00:00 | all_services   |
| 977129764170 | 2015-09-05 | 2014-10-07 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 977129764170 | 2015-05-08 | 2014-10-07 00:00:00 | widget         |
| 986629508626 | 2015-07-12 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 986629508626 | 2015-03-02 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | number_connect |
| 986629508626 | 2015-05-08 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | widget         |
| 986629508626 | 2015-01-08 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 933563888440 | 2016-02-20 | 2014-10-06 00:00:00 | all_services   |
| 933563888440 | 2015-03-12 | 2014-10-06 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 933563888440 | 2015-04-26 | 2014-10-06 00:00:00 | number_connect |
| 933563888440 | 2015-10-17 | 2014-10-06 00:00:00 | all_services   |
| 943730853721 | 2015-06-19 | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | widget         |
| 943730853721 | 2015-12-08 | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 943730853721 | 2016-02-09 | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | app_start      |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

So distinct msisdns here are 977129764170, 986629508626, 933563888440, 943730853721;

Earliest date for distinct msisdn value where action column equals 'app_start' is:

```
977129764170 is 2015-09-05
986629508626 is 2015-01-08
933563888440 is 2015-03-12
943730853721 is 2015-06-19
```

I need to make such SQL that will give me this output:

```
+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
|    msisdn    |    date    |   activation_date   |     action     |
|--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 977129764170 | 2015-09-05 | 2014-10-07 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 986629508626 | 2015-01-08 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 933563888440 | 2015-03-12 | 2014-10-06 00:00:00 | app_start      |
| 943730853721 | 2015-12-08 | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | app_start      |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

So I need to select all distinct msisdns for earliest date where app_start action occurs and join activation_date from users table by that distinct msisd. And to only look for specific date range from date column.

I tried it with this sql with no results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(log_archive.msisdn) as msisdn, DATE(log_archive.date) AS actionDate, users.activation_date

FROM log_archive 

INNER JOIN users on log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn

WHERE log_archive.action = 'app_start' && log_archive.date BETWEEN '2015-01-08' AND '2016-03-15'

ORDER BY actionDate ASC;
```

I get the same msisdn more than once even though I used DISTINCT.

Do I need to use subquery?

Comment: remove DISTINCT and use GROUP BY log_archive.msisdn

Comment: @BerndBuffen I can not do that because I will not get earliest record where log_archive.action = 'app_start' occurs. Please read the part where I explain the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a `GROUP BY` to get `MIN(date)` for each msisdn;

```
SELECT msisdn, MIN(date) date, MIN(action) action 
FROM log_archive 
WHERE action='app_start' 
  AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-08' AND '2016-03-15' 
GROUP BY msisdn
```

We also add a `MIN(action)` since we should aggregate each field that isn't grouped by and since action is the same for all selected rows, `MIN` works well.

Once you have that, adding the join is pretty straight forward;

```
SELECT a.msisdn, MIN(a.date) date, u.activation_date, MIN(a.action) action 
FROM log_archive a
JOIN users u
  ON u.msisdn = a.msisdn
WHERE a.action='app_start' 
  AND a.date BETWEEN '2015-01-08' AND '2016-03-15' 
GROUP BY a.msisdn
```

Comment: As I am now testing your sql it seams that everything works fine. Its just that I do not understand why we need to aggregate each field that is not grouped by? Thanks alot men :)

Comment: @CaslavSabani It's a requirement in standard SQL, however MySQL will by default let you get away without it (it will present the value from a pseudo random row in the group). Since the rows have the same `action` value in this case it'll give the correct result anyway, but it's a good habit to learn in case you want to use any other database system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me some pointers where I can read more about relation between GROUP BY and aggregation functions in MySQL and SQL in general. Or how can I search it in google. Where I can learn more about MySQL execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

SDISTINCT look on all returned columns, hence distinct row of returned data. So if you want only distinct rows from log_archive use it in a subquery before joining.
Like:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM log_archive) AS distinct_Log INNER JOIN...
```